# unique entity constraint using SEVERAL properties instead of one in validation.yml symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, yaml, unique-constraint

Using Symfony2.3.4, Doctrine2 and PHP5.6.3.

This is my `validation.yml` file:

```
Project\NameBundle\Entity\EntityName:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: f1
            message: "There is already an entity with the same f1"
            fields: f2
            message: "There is already an entity with the same f2"
```

This is just a visual aid to help you understand what I need. This does not work how I want to. This:

When submitting the form:
- Current behavior:

```
if(f2 is not unique)
   error;
else
   submits;
```

Expected behavior:

```
if(f1 === X.f1 AND f2 === X.f2)  //X is any of the entities already in the DB
   error;
else
   submits;
```

Just in case, I have already accomplished this in my `EntityName.php` class with `@UniqueEntity(fields={"f1", "f2"}, message="error")` annotation, but I really need it in `.yml`.

Side quest:
Right now, with the annotation approach it is showing the error sign next to only `f1`, is there a way to show it next to all involved fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields) says that fields can be array:

```
fields: [f1, f2]
```

YML format is described for example here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

Comment: in my country we have a saying "Si es un perro, te muerde". It stands more or less for "It was right f'ing there!". thnx

Comment: :) regarding your sidequest, i think you would need to add FormEvent and add error to second field manually, something like `$form->get('f2')->addError(new FormError('error message'));`